# AVAudiosession is not activate when have concurent calls active and one of them is ended

Tags: ios, iphone, avaudiosession, callkit

I start a voip call from user A to user B using call kit, sound is routed correctly. I receive other voip call on user A (user C calls A). The user A choose "Hold & Answer" option, so the B user call will set on Hold while the C user call will be routed correctly. 
At some point of time the C user ends the call so I will end up having the B user call ongoing which is on hold at this time. When the C user call is ended also the "didDeactivateAudioSession" is called. 
When I unhold the voip call I made the next actions:

```
   [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord mode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat options:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:nil];
   // unhold call
   pjsua_call_reinvite([self identifier], PJSUA_CALL_UNHOLD, NULL);
```

Reinvite is working and properly unhold, but the AVAudiosession is not activate, and of course the sound is not workign any more in the call between A and B. 
 
Also when I receive on user A the C user call disconnect, Imake the next action in order to end the C user call:

```
CXEndCallAction *endAction = [[CXEndCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:callUUID];
CXTransaction *transaction = [[CXTransaction alloc] initWithAction:endAction];
// perform transaction
[self.callController requestTransaction:transaction completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
       if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(TALoggerLevelCritical, @"\n\n ***** ERROR: Faield to end call transaction ****** \n\n");
        }
 }];
```

I had notice that when I call the request transaction also the didDeactivateAudioSession is called, even If I had other call active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I've realize that I had to unhold call in pjsip and call kit too. I had only unhold the call in the pjsip, but this isn't necessary because call kit controll the AVAudioSession and disable sound while call is on hold.

```
CXSetHeldCallAction *unholdAction = [[CXSetHeldCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:callUUID onHold:NO];
CXTransaction *transaction = [[CXTransaction alloc] initWithAction:unholdAction];
// perform transaction
[self.callController requestTransaction:transaction completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
     // finished unhold call
 }];
```